# Covariance of sampling mean and sampling variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling

Let a simple random sampling design in a finite univers U (i.e. all possible samples of size n are equally likely to occur).

> How to calculate the covariance of sampling mean $\bar{y}$  and sampling variance $s^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_{i} - \bar{y})^{2}/(n-1)$?

Comment: It is interesting to note that for a Gaussian distribution the sample mean and variance are independent and hence the covariance is 0. How this works for other distributions I am not sure about.  Have you checked this site for other posts on this topic?

Comment: Please explain what kind of sampling you are doing, with enough detail to enable us to know something about the probability distribution of $(\bar y, s^2)$.

Comment: Michael, Intuitively that covariance should also be zero...Thanks.

Comment: You could try the bootstrap --- it might give some information.  To say more, we really needs more details, as asked for.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a *moment of moment* problem ... it is often convenient to express such problems in power sum notation namely:   $s_r = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^r$. The sample mean expressed in power sums in simply $\frac{s_1}{n}$, while the sample variance can be expressed (see [for instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236742/rewriting-sample-variance-formula)) in power sums as:

$$p \; = \; \frac{1}{n-1} \sum _{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2 \quad = \quad \frac{n s_2 -s_1^2}{n(n-1)}$$

We seek $\text{Cov}(\frac{s_1}{n}, p)$ where the covariance $\mu_{1,1}$ operator is just the {1,1} product central moment. The solution can then be found using the *mathStatica* function:

[image]

where:

- $\mu_3$ denotes the $3^{\text{rd}}$ central moment of random variable $X$

The solution holds for any distribution whose moments exist. Note that if the parent distribution $X$ is symmetrical (as in the Normal case - see comments above), then $\mu_3 = 0$, and so the above covariance $\frac{\mu_3}{n}$ will also be zero.

I was not quite sure what the OP meant by 'finite universe', but if the OP is sampling *without replacement from finite populations*, then adjustments to these results are needed: there is some discussion in Stuart and Ord on how to do this.

**More detail**

There is an extensive discussion of such moments of moments problems in Chapter 7 of our book:

- Rose and Smith,  "*Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica*", Springer, NY

A free download of the written chapter is available here:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

which also includes references for further reading. For manual approaches (though this is not easy and prone to error (including many of the published results)), see:

- Stuart and Ord (1994), *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics*, volume 1, Chapters 12 and 13.